# Webscraping: descargar pdf de una web con paginación: no se descargan los pdf de todas las páginas

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

Soy nuevo en webscraping. Estoy tratando de descargar pdfs de [esta página][1], que tiene paginación (del 1 al 7). El código que he hecho solo descarga pdf de las dos primeras páginas y no encuentro cómo hacer que vaya hasta la séptima. Este es el código:

```
import os

def extract_url_pdf(input_url,folder_path=os.getcwd()):
    
    import os
    import requests
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    
    url = input_url

    #If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
    folder_location = 'D:/Datos/Ordenanzas municipales/Municipalidad de Lima'
    if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") 

    link_text=list()
    link_href=list()
    link_file=list()
    
    counter=0
    while counter < 8:
        
        postings=soup.select("h3 a")

        for link in postings:
        
            filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
            
            link_text.append(str(link.text))
        
            link_href.append(link['href'])

            link_file.append(link['href'].split('/')[-1])
                    
            print(counter, "-Files Extracted from URL named ",link['href'].split('/')[-1])
        
        next_page = 'http://www.transparencia.munlima.gob.pe'+soup.find('a', class_ = 'pagenav').get('href')

        page = requests.get(next_page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        counter += 1
    
extract_url_pdf(input_url="http://www.transparencia.munlima.gob.pe/gobierno-abierto-municipal/transparencia/mml/datos-generales/disposiciones-emitidas-1/ordenanzas-municipales/cat_view/14-documentos-mml/1-disposiciones-emitidas/77-resoluciones-ordenanzas/135-ordenanzas-municipales/2205-ordenanzas-municipales-2022?start=0")
```

También intenté con el siguiente código, con el cual solo pude descargar los pdf de la primera página. Cabe decir que se trata de archivos pdf que no tienen extensión .pdf. Por ello, se descarga como archivo sin extensión. Eso no es un problema, porque puedo luego arreglar eso de otra manera.

```
import os

def extract_url_pdf(input_url,folder_path=os.getcwd()):
    
    import os
    import requests
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    
    url = input_url

    #If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
    folder_location = 'D:/Datos/Ordenanzas municipales/Municipalidad de Lima'
    if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") 

    link_text=list()
    link_href=list()
    link_file=list()
    
    counter=0

        
    for link in soup.select("h3 a"):
    #Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
        
        filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
           f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
            
        link_text.append(str(link.text))
        
        link_href.append(link['href'])

        link_file.append(link['href'].split('/')[-1])
            
        counter+=1
        
        print(counter, "-Files Extracted from URL named ",link['href'].split('/')[-1])


for i in range (0,201,10):
    i=0
    link='http://www.transparencia.munlima.gob.pe/gobierno-abierto-municipal/transparencia/mml/datos-generales/disposiciones-emitidas-1/ordenanzas-municipales/cat_view/14-documentos-mml/1-disposiciones-emitidas/77-resoluciones-ordenanzas/135-ordenanzas-municipales/2205-ordenanzas-municipales-2022?start="+str(i)+"'
    if i > 80:
        break
    extract_url_pdf(input_url=link)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this your solution is the one that works best. Although the program cannot access some of the pages for the other years, it dowloads the vast majority of them.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre obtener una lista con el link de descarga y el nombre de la ordenanza, para finalmente descargarlas todas juntas..
Modifiqué un poco tu código, ya que dentro de la página hay ciertos elementos que pueden facilitar el trabajo, por ejemplo la paginación.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

def get_detail(element):
    return url_base + element.a.get('href')
def get_next_page(element):
    return url_base + soup.find(class_='pagination-next').a.get('href')

folder_location = '/Municipalidad de Lima'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

url_base = "http://www.transparencia.munlima.gob.pe"

href_ordenanzas = []
input_url = "http://www.transparencia.munlima.gob.pe/gobierno-abierto-municipal/transparencia/mml/datos-generales/disposiciones-emitidas-1/ordenanzas-municipales/cat_view/14-documentos-mml/1-disposiciones-emitidas/77-resoluciones-ordenanzas/135-ordenanzas-municipales/2205-ordenanzas-municipales-2022"
while True:
    response = requests.get(input_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    ordenanzas = soup.find_all(class_='dm_taskbar dm_light')
    href_ordenanzas += list(map(get_detail,ordenanzas))
    try:
        input_url = get_next_page(soup)
    except:
        break

full_ordenanzas = [[i,'ordenanza'+i.split('°')[-1].replace('-','_')+'.pdf'] for i in href_ordenanzas]
for ordenanza in full_ordenanzas:
    #print('Downloading '+ ordenanza[1])
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,ordenanza[1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(ordenanza[0]).content)
```

• Explicación del código:

`get_detail()` devuelve el `href` del elemento enviado
`get_next_page()` devuelve el `href` de la siguiente página

El algoritmo inicia haciendo una petición a la url asignada a `input_url`.

El funcionamiento del *While True* es básicamente "iterar hasta que no encuentre la siguiente página", es decir, el elemento de la clase `pagination-next`. Una vez encontrado se rompe el bucle, asumiendo que estamos en la última página.

`full_ordenanzas` es una `lista de listas` que contiene en el primer elemento de cada fila la url de descarga del pdf, y en el segundo le agrego el nombre de la ordenanza +*.pdf*. Aprovechando que dentro de la url está el numero de la ordenanza.. hago un `split('°')` para obtenerlo.

```
print(full_ordenanzas[0])
['http://www.transparencia.munlima.gob.pe/gobierno-abierto-municipal/transparencia/mml/datos-generales/disposiciones-emitidas-1/ordenanzas-municipales/doc_download/447536863-ordenanza-municipal-n°-2481-06-07-2022',
 'ordenanza_2481_06_07_2022.pdf']
```

Y el por último es el bucle para descargar los pdfs que se van a guardar con el nombre asignado en `full_ordenanzas`